# Finding the maximum in a Numpy array every nth instance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, indices

I have a large file with wind speed and direction every second. I have stored each element into a numpy array. The wind speeds for example are ws=(7, 8, 8.5, 8, 9.5). I would like to fill another array with the maximum 1 minute wind speed, so every 60 instances, I need to pull the max. I have tried this:

```
gust = np.full(len(ws), 0) 
indices = sig.argrelmax(ws)
gust[indices] = ws[indices]
```

his arbitrarily pulls out maximums and enters them successfully into an array while maintaining the same index they had in the ws array, but 1) I need it to check for maximum in batches of 60 (1-60, 61-120,...etc). 2) It turns the number in an integer and I need floats to remain as floats.

Comment: Are the number of elements a multiple of 60?

Comment: What is `sig.argrelmax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle non multiples of 60 in a more direct way you can use [reduceat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
wind=np.random.normal(size=1000)
res=np.maximum.reduceat(wind, np.r_[:wind.size:60])
```

`np.r_` creates an array of indices 0,60,120...

`reduceat` performs the ufunc `maximum` at the slices between consecutive indices

And so the last element of `res` is the max of the last 1000%60 elements of `wind`

Comment: I really like this method. How would I plug those maximum values back into an array the same size as the wind file so that I can plot the maximums along with the wind? I would like to be able to plot those maximums in the same index position as gust and wind speed will be on the same chart.

Comment: Not sure I follow, you could just change the `x` (using [np.linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)) when plotting `res`: `plt.plot(wind); plt.plot(np.linspace(60/2, wind.size, res.size), res)`

Comment: So if the wind speed array is [3,4,5,4,2], and I pull the maximum as you instructed, I would like the wind maximum array to be [ 0,0,5,0,0 ]. Same size array, but only with the max values

Answer (score 4):

If the number of elements is a multiple of 60, you can reshape the array, and then calculate the maximum over the second dimension:

```
ws.reshape(-1, 60).max(axis=1)
```

If we for example use random data, we get:

```
>>> ws = np.random.randn(7*60)
>>> ws.reshape(-1, 60).max(axis=1)
array([2.81337727, 2.30824229, 2.31009178, 2.5588816 , 3.41887582,
       2.21686554, 2.10892784])
```

If the number of measurements is not a multiple of 60, you can "*pad*" it with zeros (since the wind speed is minimum 0):

```
# padding zeros at the end
ws2 = np.append(ws, (0,) * ((60-len(ws))%60))
ws2.reshape(-1, 60).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: The particular file is in fact a multiple of 60 but would be nice to have that not be a requirement. I am plotting these values with time. The timestamps are in a second array.. So corresponding wind speed and the time it occurs will remain in the same index for plotting . Won't reshaping the wind like that mess it up? I need it to stay in the same index spot as it is in the original wind speed array.

Comment: @Jonathon: well as described you can perform padding of zeros as described at the bottom. Reshaping will not change the original numpy array, especially since reshaping is done on a *view* returned by the function, the original array remains unchanged. So we only construct a *view* and make calculations on that view, but the `ws` data remains the same.